# Infinite matrix product of matrix with an infinitesimal variable, and a constant quantity.

Tags: matrices, limits, matrix-calculus, infinite-product

Consider the matrix

$$U(\theta) = M.G(\theta)$$

where

$$G(\theta) = \begin{pmatrix} \cos(2\theta) & -i \sin(2\theta)/\sqrt{2} & -i \sin(2\theta)/\sqrt{2} \\
-i \sin(2\theta)/\sqrt{2} & \cos^2(\theta) & -\sin^2(\theta) \\
-i \sin(2\theta)/\sqrt{2} & -\sin^2(\theta) & \cos^2(\theta)  \\
 \end{pmatrix}$$

and

$$M = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

I define the repeated matrix product $P(n,\theta) = U^n$ (i.e. $P(3,\theta)=UUU)$.

I need to calculate the result of an infinite amount of these products, as the angle $\theta$ also goes to zero, but whilst the product $n\theta=\phi$ is a constant. So I need to find

$$R = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(n,\phi/n)$$

I'm really hoping I can express the matrix elements as some kind of known function(s). Please could you give me some advice on how to proceed.

Comment: Mathematica yields $R=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \cos \left(\sqrt{2} \phi \right) & -i \sin \left(\sqrt{2} \phi \right) & 0 \\
 -i \sin \left(\sqrt{2} \phi \right) & \cos \left(\sqrt{2} \phi \right) & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$.

Comment: Oh nice. Could you paste the code please

Comment: It's quite straightforward code wise, see [here](https://i.imgur.com/7QnwzeB.png). To prove the correctness of the limit you would need to diagonalise it in general.

Comment: Many thanks for your help.